# Separate Delivery order for over delivery tolerance : SD module

Tags: abap, sap-erp

i have a scenario and an abap enhancement is required by the client.The scenario is as below :

i have a sales order with 1 line item which has delivery quantity of 5000 (5.0 over delivery and under delivery tolerance).With the over delivery tolerance,i have an amount of 5250 which can be delivered. When i create a delivery order of 5000 items,it is fine.but after that,when i want to create another delivery order to for the remaining 250 ( which came from the over delivery tolerance) i am unable to create the delivery order.

What can i do to enable me to create the delivery order in this case.Need help.The client which im working on wants to maximize the sales by doing this enhancement.I previously was playing around with the vbuk status flags but it did not work. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want to create a second order? Why change the order anyway, if you have overdelivery tolerance configured? You could probably just deliver the ordered quantity + the overdelivery tolerance in a single delivery. You would need to create an enhancement that increases the delivery quantity upon delivery creation.

Comment: @GarlandGreene : its actually required by the client to maximize their profit.But your suggestion on the enhancement is the priority now for me.currently discussing with the consultant.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

An ABAP enhancement should not be necessary.  As GarlandGreene pointed out, you already have the tolerance configured, so should be able to create the delivery with 5250 already.

*Clearly you won't be able to create a delivery for 250, as that is too far under the delivery tolerance*.  Edit: I don't think this is correct, based on the fact that you can create 2 x 2500, but leaving it in for the comments below to make sense.

You also talk about playing around with VBUK status flags, I'm hoping you are using a BAPI to create the delivery, and are not trying to update SAP standard tables directly! There are a lot of interconnected functionality that SAP uses behind the scenes, and changing their tables directly can have very unpredictable results.

Comment: Esti : thank you for your feedback.I dont understand by your "as that is way under the delivery tolerance" ?

Comment: I edited the answer for clarity. If the tolerance is 5% and the sales order is for 5000 the delivery cannot be less than 4750.

Comment: i understand that we are able to create a single delivery order for 5250,but how if i want to create 3 delivery orders eg : 2500 ,2500,250 ? the standard sap allows us to create until the 2nd delivery order because the cumulative quantity reaches 5000 on the 2nd delivery order,but when you create the 3rd one of 250,we are unable to create it.Please help...i might be wrong,but the example is based on my experience.thank you

Comment: hmm, Well I do understand your problem better now, you may want to copy this comment into your question as it clarifies what you're trying to do!  Do you get a specific error message when you create the last order?  What happens if you create 2500 then 250, then 2500? If it works you may have to ensure that you never fully deliver before the last delivery, but I'm not sure how you'd be able to guarantee that.  Also try the SD forums on sdn.sap.com, as this may be a config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Part Delivery/Item indicator as 'D' in your sales order item shipping tab and then create 2500, 2500 and 250. It will allow.

Comment: Hi Nishant,i tried but failed.earlier,i was having an error saying "No delivery-relevant items in order 0000000168, order type ZOR1" but after doing the changes to the sales order as you mentioned,its showing a new error "Item 000010, matl staging date 19.01.12  replaced by current date" and "An item with no delivery quantity is not permitted. Item will be deleted"